# How to sum up distinct value using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to try and sum up distinct value from a list.. currently i am able to do so if theres only 2 similar record. If theres more than 2 i am not able to do the checking. Following is the javascript code:

```
function validateData(){
    var total = document.frm.size.value;
    var msg="";
    var tbxA;
    var tbxB;
    var tbxA2;
    var tbxB2;
    var tbxC;
    var totalValue =0;
    var repeatedValue= 0;
    var row = 0;      
    var row2 = 0;   

    for(var i=0; i<parseInt(total); i++){
        tbxA = document.getElementById('tbx_A'+i).value;
        tbxB = document.getElementById('tbx_B'+i).value-0;
        tbxC = document.getElementById('tbx_C'+i).value;
        for(var j=i+1; j<parseInt(total); j++){
            tbxA2 = document.getElementById('tbx_A'+j).value;
            tbxB2 = document.getElementById('tbx_B'+j).value-0;

            if (tbxA==tbxA2) {
                totalValue = tbxB + tbxB2;
            }
                if (totalValue != tbxC) {
                    repeatedValue= 1;
                    row = i;
                    row2 = j;
                    msg+="*total value  does not add up at row " +(row2+1);
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(repeatedValue== 1){  
        break;
        }
    }
    return msg;
}
```

For example A:type of fruit, B: total of each fruit, C: how many bought at a time
total of C should be equal to B. i.e Apple: 3+3+4 = 10. So if the total is not equals to 10 it should prompt me an error.

```
 A       B     C
 Apple   10    3
 Orange  10    10
 Apple   -     3
 Apple   -     4
```

My code above will prompt error bt it doesnt go beyond 2nd occurence of Apple.
So yes, how should i go about to ensure it loop through the whole list to sum up all similar values?

Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Comment: I don't really understand the efficiency of this script, but I can say for one that your nested `for` loop is not necessary. You only use the variable `j` for adding +1, so you can simply do `var j = i+1;`, . Furthermore, you didn't declare repeatFlag, tbxA2 & tbxB2 as variables.

Comment: @Tyblitz i need the nested for loop to do the comparison in values.. bt the problem with this loop is that it stopped looping once it found the next similar value instead of looping through the end to find the rest of the similar values. So how do I do this?

Comment: One way to do this is: 1) Make a list `[{"A":"Apple","C":3},{"A":"Orange","C":10}...]`; 2) Sort the list so that the same `A`s go together; 3) "Reduce" the list by adding each `C` to its previous item if `A` is equal.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var total = +document.frm.size.value,
    data = {};
for(var i=0; i<total; ++i) {
    var key = document.getElementById('tbx_A'+i).value;
    data[key] = data[key] || {B:0, C:0};
    data[key].B += +document.getElementById('tbx_B'+i).value || 0;
    data[key].C += +document.getElementById('tbx_C'+i).value || 0;
}
for(var i in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(i) && data[i].B != data[i].C) {
        return "total value does not add up";
    }
}
return "";
```

Some comments:

- `parseInt` (and `parseFloat`) is very slow. `+` operator before string converts it to a number much faster. But if you really want to make sure the numbers are integers, use `Math.floor()`, `Math.round()`, `Math.ceil()` or the faster but illegible `|0`.
- In case you really want `parseInt` (e.g. you want to convert `'123foobar'` into `123`), always use a radix. For example: `parseInt('123', 10)`
- Avoid doing calculations at the condition of a loop, because they run at each iteration. Just do the calculation once before the loop and save the result in a variable.

Comment: Now that looks way more efficient!

Comment: @Oriol i tried to read the data from session instead since my list is from database instead of hardcoded. does this work for that? cause I can't seem to make it work..`<%List list = (List) session.getAttribute("list");%> var data = list` wld this be right? thnks

Comment: btw.. what are .B and .C?

Comment: @user2435903 Your code seems a server-side programming language I don't know, so I can't help with that. But my code runs client-side, so they are independent.

Comment: @user2435903 Each `data[key]` is an object with two properties: `B` and `C`, which contain the sum of columns B and C associated with `key` in column A.