# Creating permutations to reach a target number

Tags: javascript, math, recursion, permutation

I have the array [1, 2, 4] and I want to make 4; I want it to return [4], not [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [2,2], [4]], I was previously doing this but I started to run out of memory when running this on a small server. I had to let the whole function run through so I could .reverse() because the last time in the array was only useful to me.

If we think of this in terms of currency, let's take [0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.2]; if I want $1, I want [1] and not [0.5, 0.5] because you always want the largest value per item right?

I'm currently using this:

```js
function getCombinations(array, sum) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        var s = t.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
        if (sum === s) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (s > sum || i === array.length) {
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 4], 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But this doesn't work backwards, so I made it iterate backwards:

```js
function getCombinations(array, sum) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        var s = t.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
        if (sum === s) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (s > sum || i === 0) {
            return;
        }
        fork(i - 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i - 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(array.length, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations([1, 2, 4], 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But this doesn't work for large-scale operations like I'm using, for example I'm trying to do:

**WARNING: THIS MAY CRASH YOUR BROWSER**

```js
function getCombinations(array, sum) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        var s = t.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
        if (sum === s) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (s > sum || i === 0) {
            return;
        }
        fork(i - 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i - 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(array.length, []);
    return result;
}

var Items = [];

for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) Items.push(0.11);
for(var k = 0; k < 197; k++) Items.push(1);

console.log(getCombinations(Items, 26.77));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: please could you define your requirement clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum up distinct value using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152332/how-to-sum-up-distinct-value-using-javascript)

Comment: How is it a duplicate? It's not anywhere near as close to what I want....

Comment: To elaborate, I want a function that takes an array and a target and uses the numbers in the array in an attempt to get to the target, if it finds a solution it will immediately return it, and nothing else. However, I want the result to be as high as possible so to get to 14, [10, 4] is better than [7, 7]. Do you understand?